# After stopping a video in PyQt5 QMediaPlayer, artifacts occur when the window is resized

Tags: pyqt5, qwidget, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

After the video has finished playing, or the QMediaPlayer stop() method has been called, artifacts occur in place of the video widget when the window is resized.
Below is a screen shot of the artifacts:
[image]
A minimal example of a program:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Player, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.open_button = QPushButton("Open Media File")
        self.open_button.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.open_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_slider)
        self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)

    def open_file(self):
        file_dialog = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Media File")
        if file_dialog[0]:
            self.set_and_play_file(file_dialog[0])

    def set_and_play_file(self, selected_file):
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(selected_file)))
        self.media_player.play()

    def update_slider(self, position):
        self.slider.setMaximum(int(self.media_player.duration() / 1000))
        self.slider.setValue(int(position / 1000))

    def set_position(self, position):
        self.media_player.setPosition(int(position * 1000))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = Player()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried monitoring the QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia state and replacing the stop() method with the pause() method, and changing the player position to 0.
This improved things to some extent, but eventually I ran into artifacts again and decided that there must be a way to get rid of this problem.
I also tried setting

```
self.video_widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent, False)
self.video_widget.setAutoFillBackground()
self.video_widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
```

but that didn't produce any results. Plus I tried to predefine `paintEvent()` in the video widget and draw a red line on the widget, but in the end, probably due to my lack of experience with QPainter, I failed and the red line was not drawn on the widget.

For now, I don't want to believe that this is a flaw in QMediaPlayer, and eventually I'll just have to accept it and look for more and more workarounds.

I am using: Windows 10 x64 1809, PyQt5 5.15.10

Comment: Assuming that you only see artifacts in the area covered by the video widget, it's possible that this may be caused by the fact that on your platform the video is shown using overlay, but when the playback ends the widget is not "notified", so the buffer of the underlying widget is not properly managed. Can you try to call `self.video_widget.testAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent)` both on playback initialization *and* when stopping? If it returns `False`, try using `setAttribute()` with the same at least when the player stops and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @musicamante testAttribute outputs False, and setAttribute didn't help

Comment: Then also try adding `self.video_widget.setAutoFillBackground()` and also try the above (test and eventually toggle) with `WA_NoSystemBackground`. Also do some tests by subclassing QVideoWidget and overriding `paintEvent()`, calling the default implementation and doing some random painting after that just to test if something is actually shown in the painter. I'd also suggest you to improve your question with all the above tests and their results.

Comment: @musicamante This also did not work, although I tried different variations of your advice. About the painter, I'm not quite sure if I was doing it right, but still, when I tried to draw a red line in the predefined paintEvent(), it was not visible on the widget. Again, I may have done something wrong as I have little experience with QPainter:(

Comment: Then edit your question with the code of those attempts

Comment: @ツDeeffest笑 Can't you just bypass the issue by setting the video output to `None` when the state changes to `StoppedState`? Or do you also get these artefacts when the player is paused?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, when I call setVideoOutput(None) and resize the window, artifacts also appear. As I said, I solved the problem by replacing stop(), but still, after playback ends I can no longer get by with the usual pause and changing the player position to 0. For some reason this method stops working (I'm tracking QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia), so now I always set the player position to 0 and pause the media. This way, when the video is resized in the video widget it also changes with the window, but the final implementation like this doesn't quite suit me and sometimes confuses me when reading it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional and, in my opinion, incomplete solution was a call to

```
import os
os.environ['QT_MULTIMEDIA_PREFERRED_PLUGINS'] = "windowsmediafoundation"
```

at the beginning of the code. This code changes the default `DirectShow` to `Windows Media Foundation`. This only works on Windows and has its drawbacks, but at least it solves my artifact problem.